# Set Destination Path for DownloadManager

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

I m using below code, but do not know where files are being downloaded. None of file stored at given path. What correction is required in code. Code is creating folder in beginning.

```
  String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Myapp/Videos";
        System.out.println(path);
        File folder = new File(path);
        if (folder.canExecute()) {
            System.out.println("Video  Folder Found");

        } else {
            folder.mkdirs();
        }

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setDescription("Selected Video is being downloaded");
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setTitle("Downloading Video");
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(mContext, null, title + ".mp4");
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        manager.enqueue(request);

        return null;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simply use

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/Path", "test.mp4");
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why i can't read this directory, when i use canRead it tells me no while i have granted ReadPermission

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solve my problem

```
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, "/path/", "MyFile.txt");
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).